# How can I join table to delete duplicates entry in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, duplicates, sql-delete, matching

I actually have this which is working :

```
DELETE FROM "WU_MatchingUsers" WHERE "id" IN (SELECT "id" FROM (SELECT "id", ROW_NUMBER() OVER( PARTITION BY "IDWU_User1", "IDWU_User2" ORDER BY "id" ASC) AS row_num FROM "WU_MatchingUsers") t WHERE t.row_num >1);
```

This delete all duplicates entry by the more recent one in "WU_MatchingUsers" but now I have another table which is : "WU_UsersSpheres" which contain Sphere id associate with user ID.

Now I would like that my query can filter / delete only Users from a specific Spheres.

So Wu_UserSpheres look like this :

```
id | idSpheres | IDUser
1       1          1
2       1          2
3       2          3
4       2          4
5       2          5
```

So the goal is to only delete duplicate of my matching where id of the users are in a specific Spheres.

Comment: can you add sample data for both tables and the exact expected results?

Comment: I already added sample for the UserSpheres, the other one is not that important it just contain id as the first query show. Also How can I show an expected results than will delete ?

Comment: Well, it is important if we want to reproduce your environment. You could show which records were deleted in the expected results by showing those that remain ;)

Comment: Just do `… FROM "WU_MatchingUsers" JOIN "Wu_UserSpheres" ON … WHERE …`?

Comment: Hey bergi I tried what you told me, it don't seems to work, I don't know if what I said is clear. I just need to filter the user by their spheres Id, I already done a script to get only id from the spheres : ```SELECT "IDWU_Users_WU_Users" FROM "WU_UsersSpheres" WHERE "IDWU_Spheres_WU_Spheres" = idSphere;``` but I don't success to add it to the query from the op.